# Unreadable Notebook in Jupyter: UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8')

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter-notebook, decoding

I created a notebook in Jupyter yesterday and today I cant open it for some reason (btw I am trying to open it on another computer, with Jupyter also)

That's what I get when trying:

Unreadable Notebook: C:\lda.ipynb UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'j\x1d\xc7\xbed,M\xac\x1e\xa0*1]\x8e\xe00\x9cd#\xc1\xba;#\x7fdm:\x14x\x95\x14j\x1a\x86\x07sn^ia\x00\xb55f\xb2\x06G\xaf\xd2\x85wHk\xeb\xbclp!\x01BB\xae\xaa\xa69

I wanted to change the encoding to utf-8 but the problem is that I dont even know what encoding is this one.

Has it happened to anyone else?

Comment: Hi, what was the operation system of the two computers? Does the notebook contain Cyrillic letters?

Comment: Windows 10 on both. Yes it does, but only like couple strings and some outputs

Comment: I'm having the same issue while trying to open another person's notebook on my computer. I tried ```jupyter notebook --help-all``` in the terminal, but there is nothing on encoding/UTF-8 there.